# Using Z-index, margin not working to push div away from another

Tags: html, css, z-index, layer

I have edited this post with my question writen in a more simple way to understand. Please see below.

Some CSS I am using:

```
#wing_right
{
  background-image:url("../images/poppadom.png");
  height:678px;
  margin-right:-60px;
  margin-left: 500px;
  position:fixed;
  right:0;
  top:240px;
  width:387px;
  z-index:50;  
}
```

Easier version of the question to understand. I hope.

Following is a diagram representation of my site. -> |LW|CN|RW|  LW = Left wing CN = Content RW = Right wing. The left and right wing have very simliar CSS. See the CSS above only difference being the image and its attached to the left wing. The content is below in terms of z-index and can't be covered by the wings. Like the very simple diagram the LW and RW move with browser resizing which is what I want. However when you make the browser window smaller I need something to prevent the LW and RW covering the content. Both wings are on the same z-index and content is on a lower z-index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the lower level content have a fixed width or is it automatic?  If it's automatic, that sounds like the correct behavior.  You could apply a minimum width to the layer you do not want "smushed" by the left and right side images.

Comment: The lower content level has a fixed width yes.

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the markup combined with the CSS to show the problem on http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: I can't really publish much more of the work I am doing as its for the client and the work isn't to be publish yet. All I can do is descibe it more.

Comment: The edited question states that the content is on a lower z-index than the wings.  Why don't you change this so the content is on a higher z-index?

Comment: Well the content slightly intersects the content area however I think I will have to add a div on the same z-index (layer) as the wings and use that. I just thought that there might have been a more elegant solution. Cheers for you help though I think I will accept that as the solution a small thin div that is over to top of an area of none content, failing that just moving some content to a higher level the content that doesn't intersect the wings.

Answer (score 0):

That element is positioned not relatively or statically so it's not "in the flow" and thus the `margin` won't affect any other div. Please post a full example, as this is a very visually involved issue.